# GIMP Segmentation fault (dl-reloc.c not found)

Tags: gimp

Suddenly my GIMP 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1 does not start any more in Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit with the latest updates as of 2017/12/04 19:48

Once I start it from the command line, it just says:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

From the GUI it does nothing.

I searched for hours on the internet and found a way to debug it:

```
gdb gimp
(gdb) run
```

The output is the following:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/gimp 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_dl_relocate_object (scope=0x7ffff7fd7358, reloc_mode=<optimized out>, 
    consider_profiling=consider_profiling@entry=0) at dl-reloc.c:232
232 dl-reloc.c: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
```

"Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden" is German and means "No such file or directory".

I really don't know what I should do! I already tried re-installing GIMP but I even didn't update it before the failure happened!

However I recently updated some libc stuff which ubuntu's update dialog suggested me.

I don't use GIMP that often but before the update it worked. **Maybe** it has something to do with the update?

---

`apt-cache policy gimp`:

```
gimp:
  Installed:           2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1
  Installation candidate: 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.8.16-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux user01 4.4.0-101-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 18:29:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`arch`:
    x86_64

`sudo apt-get check`:

```
   Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
   Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
   Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
```

This basically means that everything should work fine. The dependency tree is being built, status information are read and package lists are read as well.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` does not contain anything. And I don't think that I'm using any PPA. However I installed VirtualBox, Android Studio and  so on. Everything could be the problem!

Comment: Very strange. Please update your post with output of `apt-cache policy gimp`, `uname -a`, `arch`, `sudo apt-get check`. On my 64-bit Xenial GIMP (2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1 from universe) works good. Do you have any PPAs (add `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to the answer)?

Comment: My gimp version 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1 works well in Xenial 32-bit too, and it is updated and full-upgraded today. I would suspect some special library.

Comment: I have GIMP 2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1 as well. I am running Xenial 64-bit.

Comment: *dl-reloc.c* file is located in the glibc internals. Do you have custom kernel? Do not forget to add output of other command from my comment above.

Comment: Now I have added the requested output. Thanks for your help (and patience ;-) )

Comment: I am not using a custom kernel. I try to just use official software so that these situations won't happen.

Comment: I have the same kernel. Have you had any file-system corruption last days? Does this system run on physical hardware or VM? Could you please check integrity of the whole system with `debsums`: (install it with `sudo apt-get install debsums`, init it `sudo debsums_init`, check all system `sudo debsums --all --changed`) and add output to the answer.

Comment: This could be a clue: "However I recently updated some libc stuff which ubuntu's update dialog suggested me."; But maybe it is something very different. Maybe some file is damaged or some sector on the hard disk drive. (ninja'd by N0rbert;-)

Comment: Oh. That's a good question. I've had 2 months ago a file system corruption due to my impatience while the shutdown sequence of ubuntu which took more than 2 minutes. Please don't kill me but I did a hard reset. (-: 0

Comment: Then  I backed um some data that I could rescue and formatted my ssd ubuntu partition

Comment: But GIMP was working after the re-install of ubuntu on my real pc.

Comment: OH! Gimp-Edge works! I don't know why! But it works!

Comment: I have to go offline now but tomorrow I will dig deeper into the problem and provide the debsums output. Thank you for your help till now!

Comment: @fameman of course gimp-edge works, it is version 2.9.7 :). Had a similar situation a year back, changed to this ppa and it worked since.

Comment: 2.9.5 is quite unstable/ Either use the "gimp" PPA (gives you latest 2.8: 2.8.22, if you are on anything before 17.10), or install the [`flatpak` version](https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref).